# Css Animation: Out left and in right?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create an animation that slides out on the left side of the page, and then back in on the right side and it continues that way like on a loop. All i have so far is the code below and I'm not sure how to create what I'm trying to do. Help would be much apperciated!

```css
section {
    position: absolute;
    animation:linear infinite alternate;
    animation-name: run;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}     
  
@keyframes run {
        0% { left: 0;}
        50%{ left : 100%;}
        100%{ left: 0;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```css
@keyframes run {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
  }
  50.000001% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: linear infinite;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with two items, where one starts on screen and the other starts offscreen:

```
    body{
overflow:hidden;
}

div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:3px solid red;
  position:absolute;
 animation:move 2s linear infinite forwards;

}

div:first-of-type{
   top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left:calc(50% - 50px);
}
div:last-of-type{
   top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left:calc(150% - 50px);
}

@keyframes move{
  from{
    transform:translateX(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:translateX(-100vw)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost good, simply make the `left:100%` the final state and add a translation at the start that will hide your element at the initial state:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  animation: linear infinite;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

@keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> </div>
```